# Returning data from database to another page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

How can I return data from the database on another page?

I can file this under: views / posts / index.htm.erb

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Titulo</th>
    <th>Conteudo</th>
    <th>Categoria</th>
    <th>Criado em</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.titulo %></td>
    <td><%= post.conteudo %></td>
    <td><%= post.category.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

And I wanted to display these values ​​on another page: views / home / blog.html.erb

How do I do this? Could you explain all the steps so that I can display these values ​​in my other page.

---

Thanks Kocur4d

but how do I get only some information? eg: I would like that to appear in the title of the post page like this way (in blog.html.erb):

```
<div class="post-title">
<h2 class="title"> <a href="link_to_post"> **<% = post.titulo%>** </ a> </ h2>
</ div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1. Create controller

In your app root directory run:

```
rails g controller home blog
```

Modify **controllers/homes_controller.rb** :

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  def blog
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Your controllers/posts_controller.rb should be already set up. Minimum what you need for your question is to have index method defined you might have other methods as well:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Step 2. Extract Partial

change **views/posts/index.htm.erb** :

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<%= render partial: 'shared/posts', object: @posts %>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

create/modify **views/home/blog.html.erb** :

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<%= render partial: 'shared/posts', object: @posts %>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

create **views/shared/_posts.html.erb** :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Titulo</th>
    <th>Conteudo</th>
    <th>Categoria</th>
    <th>Criado em</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.titulo %></td>
    <td><%= post.conteudo %></td>
    <td><%= post.category.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Delete', post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

Step 3. Set up routes.

You should have something like this in your routes.rb file:

```
resources :posts or match 'posts/index' => 'posts#index'
```

add this to **config/routes.rb**:

```
match 'home/blog' => 'home#blog'
```

so it might look like this(there is few variants):

**config/routes.rb**:

```
YourAppName::Application.routes.draw do 
  root to: 'posts#index'
  resources :posts

  match 'home/blog' =>  'home#blog'
end
```

Now when you start rails server(assuming standard configuration) and visit:

**127.0.0.1:3000/posts/index** and **127.0.0.1:3000/home/blog**

you should see same content.

This should work copy-and-paste but I could make some typos and other small mistakes(hope not, if ill find any ill try to edit them asap). In general look at it as you need 3 steps to forward http request down your rails application stack.

1. Map url to controllers using routes.
2. Create controllers and inside prepare data for views.
3. Display data in Views.

Look around in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html), [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) and [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) for more info.

---------Upadate to your second question-----------

I don't really understand what would you like to achieve?? At the moment both index.html.erb and blog.html.erb showing the same data, that was what you ware asking for?

**post** representing one post and is available in sharde/_posts.html.erb. You can't reference it from index.html.erb or blog.html.erb.

**@posts** represents all the posts and its available in index.html.erb or blog.html.erb.

**render partial: 'shared/posts', object: @posts** -- this line say "Hey man! Paste here content of shared/posts file, and btw I have here a local variable @posts so if you need to use that date in shared/posts file Ill name it posts from in side there"

To make them look different modify both files and part that will be identical for both of them is in a sharde/_posts.html.erb.

Try for example remove this line:

```
<td><%= post.category.name %></td>
```

from shared  file to see what is going to happen.

Add some html tags and thinker with it.

Rails has may helper methods available' to find out about them check the links I give you and google, google, google.

Try to add some links with **link_to** helper

Comment: Hello,

I did all the steps but when I go to post / index.html.erb or home / blog.html.erb appears this error:

NoMethodError in Home # blog

undefined method `each 'for nil: NilClass

Comment: sorry change: **render 'shared/posts', object: @posts** to **render partial: 'shared/posts', object: @posts** in both files I have updated the answer

Comment: Can you help me in one more detail? I edited the page for you to see my question

Comment: Actually I did not want the two pages show the same content. I wanted the page blog.html.erb exhibited only some data from the database as the title of the post.

I'm making a blog system being that my posts/index.html.erb is my backend and home/blog.html.erb is my frontend that display information dynamically.

Comment: So I wanted to display only some information from the database in my blog.html.erb

Comment: I would suggest to go through the links I gave you. **"I wanted to display only some information from the database"** I can't clearly identify what you are asking for?? Is it that you don't want all post and just ones for example created yesterday?? Or is it that you just need to display title from all posts?? or is it mix of both?? I think that you need to read up on general topics and half of you problems will sort them self up. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your home controller, for the blog method, set @posts as you need...
Maybe

```
@posts = Post.all
```